# Connecting to localhost in Android

Tags: android, http, url, localhost, httprequest

I'm developing an App and have designed a bit of Frontend and backend, just the essential. And now, I want to connect both sides. First of all, I need to know how to connect to a localhost in Android.

I tried some tutorials in Internet using for example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
 url.openConnection();
try {
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
 readStream(in);
} finally {
 urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

I've tried several approaches but all of them fail. Some doesn't do anything and others stop the App showing some Zygote errors.

My question is clear. How can I connect to localhost in Android? I want a function of the style makeConnectionLocalHost() that returns whether the connection has been successful or not. Any idea why nothing works?

Comment: Use url as - http://10.0.2.2/test.php

Comment: Why using this URL? Why is it special?

Comment: In android if you are using localhost to connect you php pages, then you have to use like this.

Comment: Your url - http://10.2.2/<your_folder_in_htdocs>/<your_page.php>

Comment: We're not using PHP. Does it change anything?

Comment: `how to connect to a localhost in Android.`. What do you mean with localhost? Every Android device and every PC and every laptop is its own localhost. So it is unclear what you want to connect with what. Please explain first. Explain your setup.

Comment: So if a van client uses localhost or 127.0.0.1 it tries to connect with a server running on the same device.

Comment: What I want is to connect to certain IP. But to keep it simple, I would like to begin with connecting with localhost and in the future, connect to some IP where my server is.

Comment: And by "localhost" do you mean you want the phone client to connect to a server process running on the phone?  Because that's what localhost means.  Or do you want to connect to a server on your computer?  If the former, use 127.0.0.1, if the latter use 10.0.2.2, and that applies whether it's PHP or not.  That's what I use to connect an emulator to a .NET web service on the same machine.  I haven't gotten it to work with a device.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of using "localhost" your local ip. To retrieve it, open CMD and type ipconfig. There you will find your local ip.
127.0.0.1 will create a loop back to your own device.

Comment: I'm running the app on the device itself. Does it change anything?

Comment: I developed something with Volley once and had the server running on the same laptop as the emulator. When I wanted to reach the server, localhost didnt work but the local IP did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` to get `localhost` address. More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost()). And for `HttpURLConnection` you should have Web-server on this address.